# How do I add a picture to a Stack Exchange post?

Tags: support, images

I'm trying to make people see what I did. Can someone help me.

Comment: Could you please give more Information about your problem ? Where do you have your problem ? (ProfilePicture, Question with Pictures, Pictures in Answers etc.)

Answer (score 6):

You can add an image using the following markup:

`![Image description][1]`

Then at the bottom of the page, you need to add a link for the image

`[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUbiN.png`

The system supports uploading images from your PC as well as links to images.  Just click the icon that looks like a picture (6th option from the left, between {} and numbered list) and follow the instructions.  These post tools are located above the box you type in.  For more help on them, [see here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help)

If you don't want to list links at the bottom, you can keep it all in one place like this:

`![Image Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUbiN.png)`

Comment: to add, you can also do `[![Image description][1]][1]` on large images which get re-sized, this way they also become links that when licked on will open up a page where you can view the full sized image

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the above method, you can let your answer add the image automatically by clicking the highlighted button pictured below:

[image]

Comment: And please change the default description from *'enter image description here*'. People using screen-readers rely on this text to describe the image that is displayed on the screen.